# Django/Python Library for importing and producing Excel documents?

Tags: python, django, excel

Looking for an Excel library for Django and Python with specific requirements.

There looks to be a number of libraries for Django and Python that enable the user to upload an Excel document into the database.

What I am wondering is if there is a library that allows you to create an Excel document and export with conditional formatting, live formulas, creating tabs, and VLOOKUPS?

The company I work for produces Excel reports for our analysts to review that requires these types of things. Researching as we are exploring other solutions than using Access, which is it pretty easy to control Excel from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use python's xlsxwriter

```
import StringIO
import xlsxwriter

def WriteToExcel(some_data, town=None):
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)

    # Here we will adding the code to add data

    workbook.close()
    xlsx_data = output.getvalue()
    # xlsx_data contains the Excel file
    return xlsx_data
```

For further implementation:

**Source:** [How to export Excel files in a Python/Django application](https://assist-software.net/blog/how-export-excel-files-python-django-application#creating-a-working-environment)

One more useful link I found is [THIS](http://djangotricks.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-export-data-as-excel.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination of Pandas and openpyxl will do the trick!